# Regex to add a character in front of a specific character in a specific column

Tags: regex, shell, awk, replace

I have this list (for example):

```
192.168.1.76 admin password
192.168.1.90 admin pa$sword
192.168.1.12 u$er password
192.168.1.200 user pas$word
```

And I would like to add a `\` before every `$` (only in the third column).

Using awk, I tried this:

```
awk '{ gsub("$","\\$",$3); print $3 }'
```

but it return this:

```
password\$
pas$word\$
password\$
pas$word\$
```

and I would like this:

```
password
pas\$word
password
pas\$word
```

How can I do? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `awk` command only prints Column 3 values (due to `print $3`) and you just add `\$` at the end of Column 3 because `$` is an anchor that matches the line / string end position.

You may use

```
awk '{ gsub(/\$/,"\\$",$3) } 1'
```

See the [online `awk` demo](https://ideone.com/60Xc8u)

Here, `gsub(/\$/,"\\$",$3)` finds literal `$` chars and replaces them with `\$`s, and `1` at the end make `awk` print all the values.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ gsub("\\$","\\$",$3); print $3 }' file
password
pa\$sword
password
pas\$word
```

`awk`'s `gsub` function receives a `regex` as its first parameter, so you need to escape `$`.
Things inside double quotes will be expanded first, then feed to regex engine if it's a regex parameter.
So we need to use `"\\$"`, or `/\$/` for the *from* part, they work the same way.
It seems strange here, the *from* and *to* looks the same, but they're actually different.

`$` in regex means the end of a line or a field, that's why you replaced wrong place.